# rvest read_html for a specific table

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape a web page in R. In the table of contents here:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746911001056/a2201962z10-k.htm#du42901a_main_toc

I am interested in the

`Consolidated Statement of Earnings - Page 50
Consolidated Statement of Cash Flows - Page 51
Consolidated Balance Sheet - Page 52`

Depending on the document the page number can vary where these statements are.

I am trying to locate these documents using `html_nodes()` but I cannot seem to get it working. When I inspect the url I find the table at `<div align="CENTER"> == $0` but I cannot find a table ID key.

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746911001056/a2201962z10-k.htm"


dat <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Any push in the right direction would be great!

EDIT: I know of the finreportr and finstr packages but they are taking the XML documents and not all .HTML pages have XML documents  - I also want to do this using the `rvest` package.

EDIT:

Something like the following Works:

```
    url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/936340/000093634015000014/dteenergy2014123110k.htm"
    population <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/document/type/sequence/filename/description/text/div[623]/div/table') %>%
      html_table()
x <- population[[1]]
```

Its very messy but it does get the cash flows table. The Xpath changes depending on the webpage.

For example this one is different:

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/80661/000095015205001650/l12357ae10vk.htm"

population <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/document/type/sequence/filename/description/text/div[30]/div/table') %>%
  html_table()

x <- population[[1]]
```

Is there a way to "search" for the "cash Flow" table and somehow extract the `xpath`?

Some more links to try.

```
[1] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1281761/000095014405002476/g93593e10vk.htm"   
 [2] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/721683/000095014407001713/g05204e10vk.htm"    
 [3] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/72333/000007233318000049/jwn-232018x10k.htm"  
 [4] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001082/000095013406005091/d33908e10vk.htm"   
 [5] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7084/000000708403000065/adm10ka2003.htm"      
 [6] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78239/000007823910000015/tenkjan312010.htm"   
 [7] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1156039/000119312508035367/d10k.htm"          
 [8] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/909832/000090983214000021/cost10k2014.htm"    
 [9] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/91419/000095015205005873/l13520ae10vk.htm"    
[10] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000000620114000004/aagaa10k-20131231.htm"
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial. You need to select the correct part of the site first: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/

Comment: Thanks! the xpath part really helped. I have something which is messy but something to work on.